# Can I redistribute the Microsoft.Http assembly? (part of the WCF REST Starter Kit)

Tags: .net, wcf, licensing, redistributable, wcf-rest-starter-kit

I'm building an app that will be used by "anyone".

It depends on the [WCF REST Starter Kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644), specifically the Microsoft.Http.dll and Microsoft.Http.Extensions.dll assemblies.

Can I (legally) redistribute these DLLs?

I am thinking I could just copy them into the bin directory with all the other assemblies for the app.  Sound right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the License document on that site?

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/license

The pertinent part:

> "Reference use" means use of the
>   software within your company as a
>   reference, in read only form, for the
>   sole purposes of debugging your
>   products, maintaining your products,
>   or enhancing the interoperability of
>   your products with the software, and
>   **specifically excludes the right to
>   distribute the software outside of
>   your company.**

Once it is released, then I expect there would be a 'redistributable' package you can distribute with your application.

Comment: I started reading it, then my eyes glazed over and I hit my head on the keyboard.

Comment: @Cheeso - I know *exactly* what you mean. I asked a question about the 'Internal Use' Microsoft license on Server Fault a bit ago where my answer was pretty clearly in the info I'd read before :)